# Can't access my site, getting 'There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.' message

Tags: errors

my site is https://christinacreative.co.nz and I can't access it at all. Yesterday, It sent me an email for the recovery mode but the link has expired and Its not sending me another email to get back into it. I haven't been on it for months, and know there is an issue with a plugin - but I can't get into my dashboard at all. Doesn't help I dont recall my login details after not updating it for months, I only managed to get in from the email link. Any ideas on next steps? im not super tech savvy but hoping someone can help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have FTP access, you can rename the plugin directory this way. This will automatically disable all plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Access to the files on the server either by ftp or cpanel, navigate to the plugins folder and rename each plugin folder by adding a number at the end of the folder name this will fix the error.
If you already know the plugin causing the problem delete it.